# Problem with List New Form and Edit Form modal dialog configuration

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog

I created a List Definitions,with two content Type and  custom NewForm. Now I want to disable modal window only for Display Form. The property NavigateForFormsPages="TRUE" disable all modal dialogs for all forms.

Thanks.